# How to translate "tutorial"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to help translate the [Django Girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/) to Esperanto. That tutorial is a written step-by-step instruction guiding readers/learners through almost everything needed to build a functional blogging software. Besides the instructions themselves, the tutorial contains some explanations / background information about what is being done or being tried to achieve.

It's designed to be used at workshop-style courses with "coaches" present that help participants follow the guide, but should also be useful for readers learning self-guided on their own.

What Esperanto word should be chosen to translate "tutorial" in the name/title of the tutorial and elsewhere?

---

Mi volas helpi traduki la "[Django Girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/)" al Esperanto. Ĉi tiu "tutorial" estas skriba paŝon-post-paŝo-instrukcio, kiu gvidas legantojn/lernantojn tra preskaŭ tuto necesa por konstrui funkcian blogan programaron. Krom la instrukcioj, la "tutorial" enhavas kelkajn klarigojn / foninformon pri kio estas farata por atingi ĝin.

Ĝi estas destinita al metiejo-stilaj kursoj kun "trejnistoj" tie, kiuj helpas partoprenantojn sekvi la gvidilon, sed ĝi devus esti utila ankaŭ al legantoj memlernantaj.

Kiu Esperanta vorto devus esti elektata por traduki "tutorial" en la nomo/titolo de la "tutorial" kaj aliloke?

Comment: I'm unsure about the Esperanto phrasing of my question, so feel free to [edit]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ĝenerala esprimo estas „lernilo“ respektive „memlernilo“, sed tiu esprimo havas pli vastan signifon ol filmo, do „lernfilmo“ aŭ „memlernfilmo“, se temas pri simpla filmo, se temas pri interaktiva aplikaĵo, tiam fakte „lernilo“ respektive „memlernilo“ eventuale „interaktiva memlernilo“, se oni volas emfazi. El la vidpunkto de la instruisto, memkompreneble "instruilo" respektive "instrufilmo" ...

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE]! Thank you for your answer. I've [edit]ed out the salutation, because this site wants us to focus on just questions and answers. (And it's common and expected here to edit each other's content as long as the meaning isn't being distorted.)

Comment: I've accepted this answer, because "memlernilo" will probably be the term I'll use. (I guess something more specific like "memlerninstruilo" would be too awkward/redundant?)

Answer (score 2):

[Komputeko](https://komputeko.net/index_eo.php?vorto=tutorial) havas por tio la esprimojn *lernilo* aŭ *instruilo*. Ĉi-unuan mi vidis ankaŭ en alia vortaro, kaj ĝi ŝajnas al mi pli taŭga, precipe kiam temas ankaŭ pri memlernado.

Se oni volas transpreni metaforon pli klaran, estas la longe establitaj terminoj *lernolibro* (~textbook) kaj *manlibro* (~handbook), al kiuj oni povus aldoni ankaŭ *-et* por montri, ke ne temas pri veraj dikaj libroj.

Comment: Thank you. In English and German, "textbook" / "Lehrbuch" is usually more theory-heavy than practical and "handbook" / "Handbuch" has a strong connotation of being more for looking things up (i.e. being a work of reference) rather than something to work through from beginning to end as a series of exercises that built upon each other. Do _lernolibro_ / _lernolibreto_ and _manlibro_ / _manlibreto_ have a similar (here unwanted) nuance? Would _lernilo_ or _instruilo_ avoid that?

Comment: In order to avoid the nuance, which is certainly there, I proposed to add _-et-_ to show that it is something different. It may be insufficient nevertheless, so in order to be sure certainly _lernilo_ is preferable, although it is a rather general term.